# Does deleting rows from table effect on db performance?

Tags: mysql

As a MySQL database user,

I'm working on a script using MySQL database with an auto-increment primary key tables, that users may need to remove (lots of) data rows as mistaken, duplicated, canceled data and so on.

for now, I use a tinyint last col as 'delete' for each table and update the rows to delete=1 instead of deleting the row.

considering the deleted data as not important data,
which way do you suggest to have a better database and performance?
does deleting (maybe lots of) rows every day affect select queries for large tables?
is it better to delete the rows instantly?
or keep the rows using 'delete' col and delete them for example monthly then re-index the data?

I've searched about this but most of the results were based on personal opinions or preferred ones and not referenced or tested data.

---

PS) Edit:

AND Refering to the question and considering below pic, there's one more point to ask in this topic and I would be grateful if you could guide me.

[image]

deleting a row (row 6) while auto increment index was 225, leaded the not-sorted table to put the next inserted row by id=225 at deleted-id=6 place (at least visually!). if deleting action happens lots of times, then primary column and its rows  will be completely out of order and messed up.

It should be considered as the good point of database that fill up the deleted spaces or something bad that leads to reducing the performance or none of them and doesn't matter what it's showing in front!?

Thanks.

Comment: This is something you would have to benchmark for your specific use-case and see what option is more efficient. For MySQL, see [DBT2](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html) for creating automated benchmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What percentage of the table is "deleted"?

If it is less than, say, 20%, it would be hard to measure any difference between a soft "deleted=1" and a hard "DELETE FROM tbl".  The disk space would probably be the same.  A 16KB block would either have soft-deleted rows to ignore, or the block would be not "full".

Let's say 80% of the rows have been deleted.  Now there are *some* noticeable differences.

In the "soft-delete" case, a `SELECT` will be looking at 5 rows to find only 1.  While this sounds terrible, it does not translate into 5 times the effort.  There is overhead for fetching a block; if it contains 4 soft-deleted rows and 1 useful row, that overhead is shared.  Once a useful row is found, there is overhead to deliver that row to the client, but that applies only to the 1 row.

In the "hard-delete" case, blocks are *sometimes* coalesced.  That is, when two "adjacent" blocks become less than half full, they may be combined into a single block.  (Or so the documentation says.)  This helps to cut down on the number of blocks that need to be touched.  But it does not shrink the disk space -- hard-deleted rows leave space that can be reused; deleted blocks can be reused.  Blocks are not returned to the OS.

A "point-query" is a `SELECT` where you specify exactly the row you want (eg, `WHERE id = 123`).  That will be very fast with either type of delete.  The only possible change is if the BTree is a different depth.  But even if 80% of the rows are deleted, the BTree is unlikely to change in depth.  You need to get to about 99% deleted before the depth changes.  (A million rows has a depth of about 3; 100M -> 4.)

"Range queries (eg, `WHERE blah BETWEEN ... AND ...`) will notice *some* degradation if most are soft-deleted -- but, as already mentioned, there is a slight degradation in either deletion method.

So, is this my "opinion"?  Yes.  But it is based on an understanding of how InnoDB tables work.  And it is based on "experience" in the sense that I have detected nothing to significantly shake this explanation in about 19 years of using InnoDB.

Further...  With hard-delete, you have the option of freeing up the free space with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  But I have *repeatedly* said "don't bother" and elaborated on why.

On the other hand, if you need to delete a *big* chunk of a table (either one-time or repeatedly), see my blog on efficient techniques:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

(Re: the PS)

`SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` -- It is 'fair game' for the query to return the rows in any order it feels like.  If you want a certain order, add `ORDER BY`.

What Engine is being used?  MyISAM and InnoDB work differently; neither are predictable with out `ORDER BY`.

If you wanted the new entry to have id=6, that is a different problem.  (And I will probably argue against designing the ids like that.)

Comment: Thanks for your complete explanation, and I would be grateful if you guide me through the later added PS part.

Comment: @Saghachi - I added a response to your PS.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. Because DBMS systems are already designed to make changes at any time but system performance is important. Sometimes it's will affect a little bit. But no need to care it

Comment: The OP specifically asked for the answer backed by facts, not an opinion.

Comment: @Aivean - I'll back up shen's "opinion" with 21 years of "experience" that leads me to have the same "opinion".